# Does Java have byte[] xxxbuilder class just like StringBuilder for concatenating String?

Tags: java, android, string, byte

To concat multiple `String`, we use `StringBuilder` instead of `String + String` statements. Does java has such equivalent builder for `byte[]` ?

```
String[] manyStrings = {/* .... */};
String result = "";
for (String s : manyStrings) {
    result += s;
}
// StringBuilder instead of String
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : manyStrings) {
     buidler.append(s);
}
builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) for this.